# Is there a limit on tamed wolves?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to know if I can tame an infinite amount of wolves so I have a giant army of them.

Do they despawn if there are too many of them in one spot, or do they stay forever?

Comment: My son has a dozen or so tamed wolves that hang out in the front room of his house. How many in your "giant army"?

Comment: I dont know i dont even have that savegame anymore it was just hypothetical

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the code, no. You can have as many wolves (theoretically) as you want.
In practice, however, like with any mob, if you spawn too many of them Java will crash, and you will not have any dogs. I would say at maximum spawn 100.

Comment: I once spawned lots of zombies. I think they were over 100 in an obsidian box and the game has not crashed,but sounds were shorthly-cut zombie sounds and zombie movement. (The zombies were in a box to blow them with tnt) @RichardJ.RossIII

Comment: Java will not crash with just 100 entities.